# How to echo config item from config file for view in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

How to call config item from config file for view in codeigniter.

here is my config file

```
$config['user'] = array(
    'email_validation' => 'email validation',///^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
    'no_permission' => '/',
    'admin_group' => 'admin',
    'default_group' => 'default',
    'public_group' => 'public',
    'users' => 'aauth_users',
    'groups' => 'aauth_groups',
    'user_to_group' => 'aauth_user_to_group',
    'perms' => 'aauth_perms',
    'perm_to_group' => 'aauth_perm_to_group',
    'perm_to_user' => 'aauth_perm_to_user',
    'pms' => 'aauth_pms',
    'system_variables' => 'aauth_system_variables',
    'user_variables' => 'aauth_user_variables',
    'remember' => ' +3 days',
    'max' => 13,
    'valid_chars' => array(' ', '\''),
    'ddos_protection' => true,
    'recaptcha_active' => false, 
    'recaptcha_login_attempts' => 4,
    'recaptcha_siteKey' => '', 
    'recaptcha_secret' => '', 
    'max_login_attempt' => 10,
    'verification' => false,
    'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
    'name' => 'Emre Akay'
);
```

Here is my load config

```
$this->config->load('user');
```

And I will view its item for view as below

```
$site_name = $this->config->item('email_validation');
```

But is don't show any thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your config array is two dimensional array. So, you can't access directly `email_validation` without getting `user` first. Moreover, 
`$this->config->load('user');` just means loading `user.php` from `application/config/` directory. Doesn't mean loading `user` index from `$config` array. You can do it like that.

```
$userConfig = $this->config->item('user');
echo $userConfig["email_validation"];
```

**Edit**

Please make sure you config file is under `application/config/` and loaded.

```
$this->config->load('user');
```

You can check which config is loaded by doing like this.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->config);
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: What is your config file name ??

Comment: this is name of my config file user.php

Comment: It is return boolean false

Answer (score 0):

if your php version>=5.4 you can use this

```
$site_name = $this->config->item('user')['email_validation']
```